# Subject and object questions

Tags: questions, subjects, objects

I am studying the subject and object questions and I saw an example here [Asking object - subject questions. "Did" or past form of the verb in Past Simple](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84548/asking-object-subject-questions-did-or-past-form-of-the-verb-in-past-simple) but I'm not sure it that's correct:
The other example of affirmative question:

**The affirmative sentence:**
They took her home.

**Object question:**
Where did they take her?

**Subject question:**
Who they took home?

Is the subject question correct? It sounds weird for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should reference the source of the doubt.  If that is a question here, you can just post the URL and the system turns it into a nice link.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it now I can do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, the subject question should be

> Who took her home?

The subject in the affirmative statement is "They" and the object is "her".  So there are two "object form" questions

> Where did they take her
> Who did they take home.

Both have the fronted pronoun and subject-verb inversion.

The subject question simply replaces the subject with the question word "who".

Comment: Thank you so much! It confused me a lot, now it's clear!